# How to sum the cell values in datagridview with different column values

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to sum the column values in datagridview c# application

[image]

I wrote this code for sum the column value..

```
private void SetAmount()
{
  decimal ldQuantity =0.0m, ldTotalWeight=0.0m, ldAmount = 0.0m;
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    if (dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString() == "916")
    {
      ldQuantity = ldQuantity + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[4, i].Value);
      lbl916.Text = ldQuantity.ToString();
    }
    else if (dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString() == "22ct")
    {
      ldQuantity = ldQuantity + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[4, i].Value);
      lbl22.Text = ldQuantity.ToString();
    }
    else if (dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString() == "90")
    {
      ldQuantity = ldQuantity + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[4, i].Value);
      lbl90.Text = ldQuantity.ToString();
    }
    else if (dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString() == "Silver")
    {
      ldQuantity = ldQuantity + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[4, i].Value);
      lblSilver.Text = ldQuantity.ToString();
    }
    ldTotalWeight= ldTotalWeight+ Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[6, i].Value);
    lblTotalWeight.Text = ldTotalWeight.ToString();
    if (dataGridView1[8, i].Value != null)
    {
      ldAmount = ldAmount + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[8, i].Value);
      lblTotal.Text = ldAmount.ToString();
    }
  }
  //dataGridView1.Columns[4] = ldMultiply.ToString();
}
```

But as per my code its sum the cell values again and again for the same cell value...

But I want Like this

> ```
> JewelID       JewelName  Purity    Quantity
> J0001         Chain      916         4
> J0003         Kolusu     Silver      10
> ```

```
Label916Quantity.Text  = 4
LabelSilverQuantity.Text = 10
```

Kindly alter my code...

Comment: Where are you calling this "SumAmount" method?

Comment: You may want to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that shows how SO works. In addition, you may want to peruse, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also if you need [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I called that event on datagridview event...

Comment: Hmm… since there are quite a few datagridview events, can you narrow it down to which events use the “SumAmount” method? The posted code appears to work, however there are a few problems. One issue in the posted code is if there are two of the same “Purity” values. The posted code will not total them, as it appears you want to. It will display only the last “Purity” value. There are many questions but I will try to focus on your posted code.

Comment: In the posted code, when you branch back up to the `for` loop after setting the current quantity label… the `ldQuantity` varable never gets reset back to 0. Using the posted picture as an example… when the loop is first entered, `ldQuantity` equals zero, the first item sets `ldQuantity` to 2. Continuing, we loop back up for the second item “silver”… `ldQuantity` IS STILL 2. When the `if` statement gets to the silver portion it will add the current `ldQuantity` (2) plus the quantity in the cell (5) and put the incorrect value (7) into the silver label. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sir, I called the Method here

Comment: private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            SetAmount();
        }

Comment: So the “SumAmount” is called in the `RowsAdded` event and this is fine, however, have you tried to fix the totals issue you are having? As I commented earlier, the code you posted has some problems and must be fixed before it will run correctly. Did you note and understand from my last comment how the `ldQuantity` variable is not being reset to zero with each iteration of the `for` loop? This is causing the incorrect values to be displayed.